# The right phrase for 'more than more'

Tags: phrases

I want a phrase to convey when something should be done more than enough to matter.

Is it correct to use the phrase 'more than more'?

Is it common in English literature?

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence where you use "more than more"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you'd say *more than once*, but to express what you explained, you could say *more than enough.*

Certainly not *more than more*, as that's never used and sounds wrong.

Comment: Perhaps precisely due to "sounding wrong" it draws attention to the phrase and emphasises the effect of "more". What better way to say it than to say it twice?

Answer (score 4):

*More than more* isn't a phrase I am familiar with, although if presented with it I could guess its intent. It's certainly not idiomatic English.

I think the phrase you are looking for is *even more*.

For example:

> A: I have stirred this mix, can I stop?
>
> B: No, you must stir more!
>
> [5 minutes pass]
>
> A: Can I stop now?
>
> B: No! Stir **even more**!

The phrase can be used to emphatically indicate *more* without *more* having being previously used.

So this usage is also correct:

> A: Have we walked far enough yet?
>
> B: No, we must walk **even more**.

Comment: ...still more...

Comment: .and yet more!.